# Potential sign question

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy, conventions

Let's consider a positive test charge $q$ and a positive source charge $q_o$

If we take direction of $\vec{r}$ from $q_o$ to $q$, then potential energy of $q_o$ due to $q$ will be:

$$P=k\dfrac{q_oq}{r}$$

However if we reverse the direction of $\vec{r}$ from $q$ to $q_o$, will there be any change in the sign of potential energy? If yes/no , why?

> Edit @Utkarshfutous  and @ Demosthene:
>
> $$P=-\int_{\infty}^{r}\vec{F}.\vec{dr}=-kqq_o\int_{\infty}^{r}\dfrac{1}{r^2}dr\cos\theta$$
>
> Now,
>
> if $\cos\theta$ is negative when we take direction of $\vec{r}$ from $q_o$ to $q$
>
> then $\cos\theta$ will be positive when we take direction of $\vec{r}$ from $q$ to $q_o$
>
> Thus the sign of potential changes. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I am so confused as to why you'd take anything other than a straight line path for calculating potential

Comment: no the sign will be same potential energy is neither a vector nor a pseudovector

Comment: Why are you even talking about a path from q to $q_{0}$? Potential energy between charges has nothing to do with a path between them.

Comment: Remember the path in question, is one from some reference point( in this case infinity) to the location of the charge you want to find the PE Of.

Answer (score 0):

No simply because potential energy is a scalar quantity

And that's because any form of energy is a scalar quantity (and scalar quantity have no direction)

Remember it depends on electric field and distance (both vectors) but their dot product leads again to a scalar quantity

Answer (score 0):

First, remember that only differences in potential energy are physically meaningful. The potential energy in any one particular configuration can be set to whatever we want it to be.

When we talk about potential energy as opposed to difference in potential energy, we are always talking about the potential energy relative to some reference configuration in which we've arbitrarily chosen the potential energy to be zero. In the case of the potential energy of a system of two point charges,
\begin{align}
U(r) = \frac{kqq'}{r},
\end{align}
we've chosen the potential to be zero when the charges are infinitely far apart, $r\rightarrow \infty$. So when we write down $U(r)$, what we are really writing down is
\begin{align}
U(r) = \Delta U_{\infty \rightarrow r}.
\end{align}
As you note in your edit, if we change the order of integration, we change the answer we get. But this is just because we are asking a different question. When we calculate $\Delta U_{r\rightarrow \infty}$, we get the potential energy of the reference configuration relative to our configuration of interest. This is the opposite of the potential energy $U(r)$ of our configuration relative to the reference configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the definition of the path r(t) in the potential formula, potential is the amount of work done per unit charge against the electric field, in moving a charge from some reference point to its location.

The dr path has nothing to do with the path between 2 charges,
It is the path taken from infinity(reference) to its position.

I think your actually wanting to understand the potential DIFFERENCE.

in the presence of  the electric field generated by some charge q, a charge $q_{0}$ moving from position A to position B will have a potential energy  DIFFERENCE of say X. The potential energy difference of that same charge $q_{0}$ in the presence of charge q moving from B to A will be "-X" as any line integral of a Conservative field from A to B is the negative of the line integral from B to A.

Answer (score -1):

As you write it, the potential is a scalar and is thus *independent of orientation*. Notice that it's a function of $r=\lvert\vec{r}\rvert$ only.

If you "reverse the direction of $\vec{r}$", then you're simply looking at the potential of $q$ due to $q_0$.

Comment: He is talking about potential "energy " though the answer is anyway correct but for energy you last statement is of no meaning

Comment: @Utkarshfutous indeed :)

Comment: Reversing the direction of r wouldn't mean that. Reversing dr in this case would be finding the work done against the field in moving from r to infinity. OP is confusing the definition of PE and PE differencd